# Looking for Webform Calculator Experience

Tags: webform-civicrm

Has anybody experienced Webform Calculator Module with civicrm ?

Could it, for instance, enable conditions such as :

if field1= YES, then field3 = field2

or

if field1= YES, then field2=field2+30

Should (or can) field1, field2, field3 be civicrm field, or simple webform fieldsets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the 'share address of' option, set that to 'user selects' then change it to a yes/no type field and use conditionals on that.

Answer (score 1):

Coleman is listed as a maintainer for [webform_calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator) so there is a very strong chance that it works well with CiviCRM :-)

Comment: Second that! 

Comment: Thank you Aidan, but this does not help me a lot ; hoping for Coleman. What do you mean Karin ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we have used Calculator for some pretty complex stuff - first off you switch the "contribution amount' field to use the Formula widget. then you build up your calculation in the Formula Value field.

Here is a snipet of what we have put in the Formula value field

> ({civicrm_1_contribution_1_cg10_custom_118}*30)+({civicrm_1_contribution_1_cg10_custom_122}*25)+({civicrm_1_contribution_1_cg96_custom_287}*80)+({civicrm_1_contribution_1_cg96_custom_293}*30)+({civicrm_1_contribution_1_cg96_custom_294}*30)+({civicrm_1_contribution_1_cg96_custom_295}*8)

Outcome for us is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pete : I keep this in mind (can be an alternative to my second example). But what I want to actually do is : a Webform to record a couple for an event, each with his/her address, so that if they have the same address, the second is automatically filled with the first. (I would rather expect a conditionals extension). Any idea ?

Comment: sorry. reread your question. you could use the 'share address of' option, set that to 'user selects' then change it to a yes/no type field and use conditionals on that. i don't think you can add data in to a field from another field on the form unless you just js

Comment: ps I thought Conditionals was now in-built in Webform

Comment: Thanks again Pete ; I did not think of that "share address" option, which looks fine for my problem. BTW, Conditionals are included in webform (I use them a lot), but are too limited to meet my wishes. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.